Как реализовать данное меню?
Имеется такое меню (Telegram Android). Секция "Настройки" и таких секций может быть много. В этой секции у нас будут пункты и если мы кликаем на какой-то из пунктов, представим это "Устройства", то нужно поменять это меню на меню с устройствами. Если скажем у нас пункт "Тема" и у нас там select, то просто меняем тему. Как такое сделать на React? Искал в интернете и ничего не нашел. Каждый пункт из секции должен выполнять свои действия, это: смена на другое меню, скажем просто вывести в консоль сообщение и т.д


Все просто можно через массив массивов, просто в стейте храните индексы пути к меню при переходе, последний массив в пути отрисовываете, путь - важен в любой реализации

Очень сложно ))))) Можете пожалуйста показать примером? :)

Нет писать код не буду, только после Вас:) тут так принято, это решение самое простое из тех что Вам предложат (если предложат, а не минусанут вопрос)

Да вот я не могу даже понять как правильно его написать :)

Если умеете работать с массивами справитесь, кликнули по пункту 3 значит в массиве это 2 индекс, переходите дальше или делаете действие, путь можно хранить как строку «2-0-5…»

Если это конечный пункт меню делайте его объектом иначе массив (подменю) Из стейтов тут только путь

Хорошо! А если у меня вот секция одна будет грузиться из сервера, то тогда как? :)

Можете сделать специальным объектом, отобразить лоадер и при резолве fetch отобразить что пришло

Капец! Мне даже сложно написать этот массив, не могу понять как правильно :D

Как можете так и пишите, тут неполучится ошибиться: меню — массив, подменю — тоже массив, конечный пункт меню — объект, подгружаемое меню — на усмотрение

Начните с малого Как отрисовать список в react. Далее как рендерить вложенные списки
